# How to develop the website in Kannada Language in Joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla3.0, multilingual, joomla-extensions

I want to develop the website in Kannada and English Language in Joomla 3.x.

I am not getting the Joomla Kannada language pack anywhere. How I can develop in Kannada. Is there any extensions/plugins available to do the same?

Answer (score 3):

Joomla is an Open source project so you can translate it in Kannada.

You can see all the available translations here :
[available joomla language](http://community.joomla.org/translations/joomla-3-translations.html)

I’m afraid i don’t see your language.

In order to make a language pack for joomla, you can follow this tutorial :

https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Making_a_Language_Pack_for_Joomla